Understanding the handling of strings in C++ on Windows
When I run this simple program on Linux (Ubuntu):
int main() {
        const char* s = "olé";

        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

I get:
olé

Now contrast the same program on Windows:
int main() {
        LPCSTR s = "olé";      
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

This gives me:
ol├⌐

I think I can understand why this could be so e.g., after reading this. The surprise comes when I try to run following program (on Windows):
int main() {   
        LPCWSTR s = L"olé";
std::wcout << s << std::endl;
}

Note the use of std::wcout in above. I would expect this to print the original string olé but instead I get:
olΘ

Can anyone explain:

Why?

Is there any way to get C++ to print the original string on Windows?



Can't replicate https://godbolt.org/z/echGj97rY. Looks like a terminal or file save encoding issue.

I can replicate the 2nd output on VS2022 (v17.11.2) with unicode character set, not the first one though (probably because of the charset). This é is (extended) ASCII 130. But the output is OK when redirecting it to a file (program.exe > output.txt) so the explanation of a terminal issue is likely.

This has everything to do with the capabilities of the console (or terminal) on different operating systems and very little to do with C++. The only C++ aspect is that it does not provide any built in support for Unicode or any other character set. All these issues are QOI issues for the particular IDE/compiler/operating system combination that you are using. It's not a good situation, but it is what it is. The reason is that C++ predates the widespread adoption of Unicode, and for whatever reason the C++ standards committee have not felt able to bring C++ up to date since then.

If I redirect the output to a file I do get olé for the first case (using LPCSTR with std::cout) and the second case gives ol□  (using LPCWSTR with std::wcout). So you are right about terminal issue. further, question remains why the second case does not give olé  as expected?

You have to call an obscure Microsoft function to set your stdout to UTF16 as shown here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170
The following few lines, built in VS2022 as console app, reproduce your issue. Uncommenting the _setmode call fixes it:
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main() 
{
    //_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"olé\n";
    return 0;
}


thanks for the answer. It looks useful but for me, uncommenting _setmode does not print anything. I also don't see any exception being caught in try catch. I am compiling with /EHa switch and have a catch (...) block in addition to catch (std::exception& E)

I'd try literally building just my couple of lines, and start debugging from there.

I tried this again today and just your code. Got it to work with this cl /utf-8 /std:c++17 /EHsc test3.cpp. The /utf-8 switch is really important.

In the 1st example, your source file is likely encoded in UTF-8, so your literal gets saved as-is in the executable as UTF-8, but your terminal on Windows is not configured to display UTF-8. Whereas on Linux, it likely is.
In the 2nd example, your source file is likely encoded in UTF-8, but you are probably not telling the compiler to parse the file as UTF-8, so the literal does not get setup correctly.
